# Storyboard UITableViewCell could not load nib in bundle with name... when loaded programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, storyboard, nib

I have a Viewcontroller scene (Storyboard) with a `UITableView` and inside a `UITableViewCell` called **Foo**. **Foo** loads fine when loaded from a storyboard, but I need to load it from another `UITableView` programmatically.

I'm registering the cell like this (at first I tried without `UINib` but `IBOutlets` were `nil`):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()        
    tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "Foo", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "bar")
}
```

and then loading it like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "bar", for: indexPath) as! Foo
    return cell
}
```

This doesn't work and returns the error:
*Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle <[path]> (loaded)' with name 'Foo''*

Things I made sure of:

- The **Foo** `UITableViewCell` identifier in Attributes inspector is *Foo*
- Has the correct Target Membership

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to create a separated nib file for your cell then register it to your table view like what you've done above.

Comment: The thing is I don't use Storyboards, that's why I'm doing this programmatically, isn't it possible to do it without moving the `UITableViewCell` outside the `UItableView`?

Comment: If you want to reuse your table view cells, then you should move it to a separate nib file. After that, you can register that cell to any table view you want. If you keep your cell inside a table view within a view controller in a storyboard file, then you have no way to reuse it.